# Pass datetime parameter in OPENROWSET query

Tags: sql-server-2008, openrowset

When I am passing datetime parameter in `OPENROWSET` query, I get the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
    'SERVER=localhost;UID=test;PWD=test', 
    'set FMTONLY OFF exec testdatabase.dbo.Proc_Salaryslip_PF '','','','',''5112'','','','','',''8'',''2012'','','',''0'',''1'',A,20120401,20130301,''Y'',''Y'','',A,admin,0,N,'',''18'' ')
```

Please suggest some solution, my project is depending upon your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These looks suspicious `20120401,20130301`. If they are passed to a `datetime` parameter you will get:

> Error converting data type int to datetime.

Since you pass them as integer instead of string literal. To fix that you have to quote them as strings.

But since that is not the error you get you are passing another parameter as a string to a `datetime` parameter.

Here is the parameter list you use, one row for each parameter. Check against the declaration of your procedure.

```
exec testdatabase.dbo.Proc_Salaryslip_PF 
',',
',',
'5112',
',',
',',
'8',
'2012',
',',
'0',
'1',
A,
20120401,
20130301,
'Y',
'Y',
',A,admin,0,N,',
'18'
```